# Problems with video playback using the ffplay

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avi, libav

everyone. I have problems with [video](https://itvgroup-my.sharepoint.com/personal/anzor_gergov_ru_axxonsoft_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?folderid=03974690133d746b6885e806dd22760b4&authkey=AZNS7ZzstcxARjOp6XeX2kk) playback using the ffplay. Used the following command

```
ffplay -i input.avi
```

But the following error occurred.

```
ffplay version N-87353-g183fd30 Copyright (c) 2003-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 76.100 / 55. 76.100
  libavcodec     57.106.101 / 57.106.101
  libavformat    57. 82.101 / 57. 82.101
  libavdevice    57.  8.101 / 57.  8.101
  libavfilter     6.105.100 /  6.105.100
  libswscale      4.  7.103 /  4.  7.103
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
[avi @ 00000000024bd9e0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none (HEVC / 0x43564548), none, 1920x1080, 1697 kb/s): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, avi, from 'c:\problem.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:25.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1701 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: none (HEVC / 0x43564548), none, 1920x1080, 1697 kb/s, 30.92 fps, 30.92 tbr, 30.92 tbn, 30.92 tbc
No codec could be found with id 0
Failed to open file 'c:\problem.avi' or configure filtergraph
```

This video is playable without any problems via the VLC, Media Player Classic. 
After trying to find out more information about the video file, I used ffprobe command

```
ffprobe -v 0  c:\problem.avi -print_format json -show_format -show_streams

{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_tag_string": "HEVC",
            "codec_tag": "0x43564548",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 1080,
            "has_b_frames": 0,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "0:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "0:1",
            "level": -99,
            "r_frame_rate": "773/25",
            "avg_frame_rate": "773/25",
            "time_base": "25/773",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 773,
            "duration": "25.000000",
            "bit_rate": "1697304",
            "nb_frames": "773",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "c:\\bin\\Virtual\\problem\\problem.avi",
        "nb_streams": 1,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "avi",
        "format_long_name": "AVI (Audio Video Interleaved)",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "25.000000",
        "size": "5318210",
        "bit_rate": "1701827",
        "probe_score": 100
    }
}
```

What could be the problem with this videofile?

Comment: The problem is most likely the AVI container.

Comment: Try `ffplay -probesize 40M -analyzeduration 40M -i input.avi`

Comment: Tried this command, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You could playback this video by explicitly setting the HEVC decoder:

```
ffmpeg -codec:v hevc -i input.avi
```

The reason is probably is that AVI container can't actually contain HEVC data. Luckily it's possibly to know that is in it by running `ffprobe input.avi` and examining streams.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there was a bug in the ffmpeg to support HEVC and/or AVI container.
Many a times it is best to discuss such issues in the [ffmpeg forums](https://ffmpeg.org/contact.html#Forums).
Developers input can help a lot! Or may be you had some older version of the ffmpeg binaries.

Here is the output from the latest ffmpeg binaries.
I can see that there are differences in the initial stream info, codec level, color, pixel formats.
And this file plays well on my setup.

```
PS C:\temp> ffmpeg.exe -version
ffmpeg version git-2020-06-28-4cfcfb3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200621

PS C:\temp> ffprobe.exe -v 0 C:\temp\problem.avi -print_format json -show_format -show_streams
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "hevc",
            "codec_long_name": "H.265 / HEVC (High Efficiency Video Coding)",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "25/773",
            "codec_tag_string": "HEVC",
            "codec_tag": "0x43564548",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 1080,
            "coded_width": 1920,
            "coded_height": 1080,
            "closed_captions": 0,
            "has_b_frames": 0,
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 123,
            "color_range": "tv",
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "r_frame_rate": "31/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "773/25",
            "time_base": "25/773",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 773,
            "duration": "25.000000",
            "bit_rate": "1697304",
            "nb_frames": "773",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "C:\\temp\\problem.avi",
        "nb_streams": 1,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "avi",
        "format_long_name": "AVI (Audio Video Interleaved)",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "25.000000",
        "size": "5318210",
        "bit_rate": "1701827",
        "probe_score": 100
    }
}
```